# lock user input into a control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-input

ok, this is an off-shoot of a question i asked yesterday, but i felt it deserved it's own post.  i made this control:

```
public partial class LinkLabelTextBoxPlayerName : UserControl
{
    public LinkLabelTextBoxPlayerName()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.textBox.Hide();
    }

    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.linkLabel.Hide();

        this.textBox.Show();
        this.textBox.Focus();
        this.textBox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(textBoxPlayerName_KeyPress);
        this.textBox.LostFocus += new EventHandler(textBoxPlayerName_LostFocus);
    }

    private void textBoxPlayerName_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter && !(String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBox.Text)))
        {
            this.linkLabel.Text = this.textBox.Text;
            this.textBox.Hide();
            this.linkLabel.Show();
        }
    }

    private void textBoxPlayerName_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBox.Text)))
        {
            this.linkLabel.Text = this.textBox.Text;
            this.textBox.Hide();
            this.linkLabel.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

it is a LinkLabel==>Textbox control, and it works about 95%, here is the problem, when user input cliks the linklabel, and turns it into a textbox, i want it to "lock" user input to only the textbox, otherwise, you can keep clicking linklabels, activatin more textboxes.  im just wondering if there is a way to disable user input while the textbox is active.  Thanks for any help.

i changed part of the method from

```
{    
    this.textbox.Focus();
}
```

to

```
{     
     this.textBox.Hide();
     this.linkLabel.Text = "<click to add player>"; //my orginal link label text;
     this.linkLabel.Show();
}
```

so this seems to be working.

Comment: You mean don't allow the user to get out of a textbox? Or in other words put focus back to textbox when user try to move out of it?

Comment: your problem could have been in the `textBoxPlayerName_LostFocus` method.  It is giving focus to the current instance of the object when the textbox is empty, but isn't hiding the other instance that just received focus.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and add a static "Who has focus" variable, and when you give focus to one you take the old static var and make it show the label.

e.g.

```
private static LinkLabelTextBoxPlayerName _curSelected;
...
if(_curSelected != null)
{
    _curSelected.Blur();
}

_curSelected = this;
```

This is assuming that you want only one Textbox open at a time and that isn't what is working.

Answer (score 1):

I would set the `CausesValidation` property to true for the field you wish to lock user into.

Then, in the `Validating` event handler, I'd use;

```
private void control_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if( ! allowUserToLeaveControl )
      e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Hope this works for you!

/A

Answer (score 0):

im sorry i asked this, i should have just put a little more time into it, here is code that works fine,

```
public partial class LinkLabelTextBoxPlayerName : UserControl
{
    public LinkLabelTextBoxPlayerName()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.textBox.Hide();
    }

    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.linkLabel.Hide();

        this.textBox.Show();
        this.textBox.Focus();
        this.textBox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(textBoxPlayerName_KeyPress);
        this.textBox.LostFocus += new EventHandler(textBoxPlayerName_LostFocus);
    }

    private void textBoxPlayerName_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter && String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBox.Text.Trim()))
        {
            this.textBox.Hide();
            this.linkLabel.Text = "<click to add player>"; //orignal text;
            this.linkLabel.Show();
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            this.textBox.Hide();
            this.linkLabel.Text = this.textBox.Text;
            this.linkLabel.Show();
        }
    }

    private void textBoxPlayerName_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBox.Text.Trim())))
        {
            this.textBox.Hide();
            this.linkLabel.Text = this.textBox.Text;
            this.linkLabel.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox.Hide();
            this.linkLabel.Text = "<click to add player>"; //orginal text;
            this.linkLabel.Show();
        }
    }
}
```